# cant run boot2docker in win 7 64bit strange virtual box error

Tags: docker, virtualbox

when I do boot2docker -v start and get the following error trail

```
    2015/03/21 21:32:09 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
2015/03/21 21:32:13 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountPrefix
 /
2015/03/21 21:32:14 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 guestproperty set boot2docker-vm /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/SharedFolders/MountDir /
2015/03/21 21:32:14 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm --name c/Users --hostpath C:\Users --automount
VBoxManage.exe: error: Shared folder named 'c/Users' already exists
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE (0x80bb000c), componen
t SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "CreateSharedFolder(Bstr(name).raw(), Bstr(hostp
ath).raw(), fWritable, fAutoMount)" at line 1009 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
2015/03/21 21:32:14 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 setextradata boot2docker-vm VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/c/U
sers 1
2015/03/21 21:32:14 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 startvm boot2docker-vm --type headless
Waiting for VM "boot2docker-vm" to power on...
VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'boot2docker-vm' has terminated unexp
ectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in
 'D:\ebcidic\Hadoop\cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.3.0-0-virtualbox\cloudera-quickstar
t-vm-5.3.0-0-virtualbox\boot2docker-vm\Logs\VBoxStartup.log'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component Machine, int
erface IMachine
2015/03/21 21:33:15 executing: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
 showvminfo boot2docker-vm --machinereadable
error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm" (run again with -v for de
tails)
```

when digging into the virtual box logs I get the following

```
    1d50.21a8: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\system32
1d50.21a8: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening vboxdrv stub...
1d50.21a8: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Restoring LdrInitializeThunk...
1d50.21a8: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Returning to LdrInitializeThunk...
1d50.21a8: Registered Dll notification callback with NTDLL.
1d50.21a8: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll)
1d50.21a8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
1d50.21a8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll (Input=kernel32.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0xffffffff pwszSearchPath=0000000000000000:<flags> [calling]
1d50.21a8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
27fc.1d84: Error (rc=258):
27fc.1d84: Timed out after 60001 ms waiting for child request #1 (CloseEvents).
27fc.1d84: Error 258 in supR3HardNtChildWaitFor! (enmWhat=5)
27fc.1d84: Timed out after 60001 ms waiting for child request #1 (CloseEvents).
```

can please someone help me in figuring out what the real issue is .I usually dont use virtual box as it flushes errors but seems thats the way to go with docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the following steps solved it

1. Installing virtualbox 4.3.12
2. Then following the instructions here https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/625 to get rid of the tcp errors coming.

Hope it helps !